# Post Array Json to .net core web api controller

Tags: c#, .net, json, post, asp.net-web-api

I have this code

```
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public IActionResult Add([FromBody] Player player)
    {
        PlayerService.Add(player);
        PlayerService.SaveChanges();
        return Created("Player created",player.Name);
    }
```

and this json

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Olivier Giroud",
    "league": "Premier League",
    "currentTeam": "Arsenal"
  }
]
```

and everything is going ok.
But if i want to send a json array

```json
[ 
  { "name": "Olivier Giroud", "league": "Premier League", "currentTeam": "Arsenal" },    
  {"name": "Lucas Perez","league": "Premier League","currentTeam":"Arsenal"}
]
```

i get an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
". I tried with List

```json
public IActionResult Add([FromBody] List< Player >  players)
```

or

```json
public IActionResult Add([FromBody] IEnumerable < Player >  players)
```

or

```json
public IActionResult Add([FromBody] Players[] players)
```

but without success. What should i do?

Answer (score 6):

Try changing

```
public IActionResult Add([FromBody] Players[] players)
```

To

```
public IActionResult Add([FromBody] Player[] players)
```

Comment: I tried with Player[] players, actually. That was a mistake.

Comment: Solved. Thank you for your answers